# envp in execve system call contain nothing execpt of the string" LS_C"

Tags: c, linux

I bullied simple monitor that print the path of the file that been execute so i hooked the execve system call but the problem was that the file name parameter contain only the file name and not the all path. any way i copied the envp parameter and i printed every string in it 
but the out put was just LS_C so i am wondering where do the execve system call get path from
this is my code:

```
static asmlinkage long our_execl(const char __user * filename,
            const char __user * const __user * argv,
            const char __user * const __user * envp) {
copy_from_user(mid,envp,sizeof(envp));
 printk("okdotk:%d\n",sizeof(envp));
for(i=0;i<sizeof(envp);i++)
{
strncpy_from_user(env, mid[i], sizeof(mid[i]));
env[255]='\0';
printk("%s\n",env);

reset_envp(sizeof(env));
}
```

return original_call(filename,argv,envp)
}

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(envp)` is the `sizeof` a pointer which on your system is 4. It's not the length of the array.

Therefore, your code merely shows the first 4 letters `LS_C` of a single environment variable `LS_COLOR=..`

You should instead iterate until `envp[i]` is NULL, signaling the end of the environment. For each environment variable, you should copy until you see a `\0`, and again not stop after the first 4 bytes.

Comment: but i can't check the envp[i] before copy it to kernel space so how should i get the size of the array?

Comment: You can't get the length of the array up front, just like how you can't get the length of a string up front. You have to search it until you find the terminator (the `char** envp` is terminated by NULL the same way `char*` is terminated by `\0`)

Comment: and one more question I did what you sad and it worked just fine but i got list of number and variables so maybe you know how to get the PATH variable

Comment: You would have to iterate over all entries and do a string comparison to find the one that starts with `PATH=`. Then you cut off that prefix.

Comment: there is only one entry and it looks like that                   hihi:LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:

Comment: Are you saying that when you examine `envp[1]`, it's NULL? What's your current code?

Comment: ok so I found out that there is 10 entries but steal none of them is the PATH variable                                                                            [ 4053.533340] 1:LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
[ 4053.533345] 2:XDG_MENU_PREFIX=xfce-
[ 4053.533348] 3:LANG=en_IL
[ 4053.533352] 4:GDM_LANG=en_US
[ 4053.533355] 5:DISPLAY=:0.0
[ 4053.533358] 6:GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0
[ 4053.533361] 7:COLORTERM=truecolor
[ 4053.533365] 8:XDG_VTNR=7
[ 4053.533369] 9:SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh

Comment: Please post your updated code.  It's not clear exactly what you have changed, so we can't guess what your code is actually doing now.

Comment: You should verify that you are in fact getting all variables, and that you can in fact see it when you make sure to pass it from userspace. In that case, [POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) "If [PATH] is not present, the results of the search are implementation-defined."

Comment: If you want the contents of the `PATH` environment variable, then suggest using: `char *ptrToPath = getenv( "PATH" );`